# Template specialization alias

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I have a problem I came up with recently. I actually think it can not be solved as I would like it to be, but it would be quite handy if it could. Anyway, here's the problem:

I will give you an example I've seen a few days ago on this forum since it will be easier to explain with it. Let's say I'm trying to create a Tensor struct, this way:

```
template <int N>
struct Tensor
{
    Tensor<N - 1> x;
    Tensor<N - 1> y;
    Tensor<N - 1> z;
};
```

To avoid infinite recursion, I would have to write the template specialization for N = 1.

```
template<>
struct Tensor<1>
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

Actually, when N = 1, this Tensor is actually a Vector (physical one). Let's say I already have a Vector struct defined this way:

```
struct Vector
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

This struct is exactly like Tensor<1>. Since the Vector struct already existed and, let's say I did not implemented it myself, I would like to be able to make the Tensor<1> struct an alias of the Vector struct. Just like a typedef. So, I would like to do it this way:

```
// C++03
typedef Vector Tensor<1>;

// or C++11
using Tensor<1> = Vector;
```

This way, Tensor<1> and Vector would be the exact same struct, so it would I could use one instead of another in the program wherever I want and I would not have to write the same struct twice.

However, it's actually impossible to define a template specialization that way. If it was, I would not be asking the question there.

**Note:** I know the previous example is not a good one since we can still do this:

```
using Vector = Tensor<1>;
```

But it is quite bothersome if I want to do it with specializations of two different structs. For example when writing a geometry library that could compute geometry in N-dimensional spaces:

```
using Circle<2> = Hypersphere<2>;
```

So, to sum up: is there a way to create template specializations by defining it as the alias of another one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given legacy classes Scalar, Vector and Matrix, you could use inheritance:

```
template<>
class Tensor<0>: public Scalar {};

template<>
class Tensor<1>: public Vector {};

template<>
class Tensor<2>: public Matrix {};
```

Note that this is not abuse of inheritance because you are modelling an is-a relationship.

Comment: Yeah, I already thought of that, but if I did so, the classes would not be the "exact same". I mean I would have to cast and down_cast to pass variables from one type to the other :/
I know it's just a detail and perhaps is it not considered as type safe to think those classes the way I do, but it's exactly the detail I would like to overcome.

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Morwenn For more generality, your example would need two template parameters: `template<size_t N, size_t D = 3> class Tensor<N, D>. Here, D would be the number of spatial dimensions.

Comment: Yes, but I just shew this example just to expose a syntaxical problem. I don't use Tensors myself or anything. It was just to clear my mind about C++ possibilities^^"

Comment: @Morwenn You don'thave to worry about casting: you can simply pass a Tensor<1> where a Vector is needed because there is no slicing (this is simple Liskov-substition). And you can avoid to cast the other way around as long as Vector has a copy constructor. (i.e. just write a Tensor<1>::Tensor(const Vector&) constructor that uses the Vector copy constructor.)

Comment: Yeah, that's right. It's not as "beautiful" as I would have wanted since these will be two different classes anyway, but it can still be easy tu use it that way.
Thank you for all :)

Comment: For a legacy `class Vector` where you don't have the source, this is as much you can do AFAICS. If you have the source, you could rename `Vector` to `template<> Tensor<1>` and then do `typedef Tensor<1> Vector;`

Comment: This last solution is why I said my example was bad and why I gave the one with Circle<2> and Hypersphere<2> since an hypersphere and a circle are the same geometrical object in a 2 dimensional space. In this last example, I can't use typedef and have to use inheritance as you proposed ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10862/discussion-between-rhalbersma-and-morwenn)